# Notation Explanation

Tags: notation

[Here](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matlhh/preprints/Banach%20Stone.pdf), page $3$, there is this notation $\bar{P}^{\beta X}$. I know that $\beta X$ is the stone-Cech compactification of $X$, but authors do not define what is $\bar{P}^{\beta X}$. Is it the set of all functions from $\beta X$ to $\bar{P}$?

Comment: Without looking at the reference, I would blindly guess "yes"--either that, or the set of *continuous* such functions. But I may have just put my foot in my mouth ;)

Comment: And now that I've looked, I see I was wrong. I think it means the closure of $P$ in $\beta X$.